# Getting error with Pytorch lightning when passing model checkpoint

Tags: pytorch, pytorch-lightning

I am training a multi-label classification problem using Hugging face models. I am using Pytorch Lightning to train the model.

Here is the code:

And early stopping triggers when the loss hasn't improved for the last

```
early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)
```

We can start the training process:

```
checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
  dirpath="checkpoints",
  filename="best-checkpoint",
  save_top_k=1,
  verbose=True,
  monitor="val_loss",
  mode="min"
)


trainer = pl.Trainer(
  logger=logger,
  callbacks=[early_stopping_callback],
  max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
 checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
  gpus=1,
  progress_bar_refresh_rate=30
)
# checkpoint_callback=checkpoint_callback,
```

As soon as I run this, I get this error:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/connectors/callback_connector.py in _configure_checkpoint_callbacks(self, checkpoint_callback)
     75             if isinstance(checkpoint_callback, Callback):
     76                 error_msg += " Pass callback instances to the `callbacks` argument in the Trainer constructor instead."
---> 77             raise MisconfigurationException(error_msg)
     78         if self._trainer_has_checkpoint_callbacks() and checkpoint_callback is False:
     79             raise MisconfigurationException(

MisconfigurationException: Invalid type provided for checkpoint_callback: Expected bool but received <class 'pytorch_lightning.callbacks.model_checkpoint.ModelCheckpoint'>. Pass callback instances to the `callbacks` argument in the Trainer constructor instead.
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look up the description of the `checkpoint_callback` argument in the documentation page of [`pl.Trainer`](https://pytorch-lightning.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.html?highlight=Trainer#pytorch_lightning.trainer.trainer.Trainer):

> `checkpoint_callback` (bool) – If `True`, enable checkpointing. It will configure a default `ModelCheckpoint` callback if there is no user-defined `ModelCheckpoint` in callbacks.

You shouldn't pass your custom `ModelCheckpoint` to this argument. I believe what you are looking to do is to pass both the `EarlyStopping` and `ModelCheckpoint` in the `callbacks` *list*:

```
early_stopping_callback = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', patience=2)

checkpoint_callback = ModelCheckpoint(
    dirpath="checkpoints",
    filename="best-checkpoint",
    save_top_k=1,
    verbose=True,
    monitor="val_loss",
    mode="min")

trainer = pl.Trainer(
    logger=logger,
    callbacks=[checkpoint_callback, early_stopping_callback],
    max_epochs=N_EPOCHS,
    gpus=1,
    progress_bar_refresh_rate=30)
```

Comment: I am having a similar error 
```
You passed a `pytorch_lightning` object (ModelCheckpoint) to a `lightning.pytorch` Trainer. Please switch to a single import style
``` 
but this didnt solve it